# Vue.js go back button browser detail back to lister position

Tags: vuejs2

I have a test lister products and detail. Now when i go back with de backbutton in the browser is doesn't go back to the wright position.

So if i scroll down in the lister , click product to detail and back it doesn't go to the position i clicked before.

How can i achieve that?

Main.js

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Router:

export default new Router({
        mode: 'history',
        scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
            if (savedPosition) {
                console.log(savedPosition)

```
            return savedPosition;

        } else {
            return {x: 0, y: 0};
        }
    },
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/products',
            name: 'Products',
            component: Products,
            props: true,
        },
        {
            path: '/product/:id',
            name: 'Productdetail',
            component: Productdetail,
            props: true
        }
    ]
})
```

Lister:

```
<template>
    <ul v-if="posts && posts.length">
        <li v-for="post of posts"  v-bind:id="post.id">
            <p><strong>{{post.title}}</strong></p>
            <p>{{post.body}}</p>
            <router-link :to="{path: '/product/'+post.id, replace: true}">{{post.title}}</router-link>

            <hr>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

import axios from 'axios';

export default {

    name: 'Products',
    props: ["guid"],
    data() {
        return {
            posts: [],
            msg: 'Products'
        }
    },
    created() {
        axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(response => {
                // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                this.posts = response.data
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e)
            })

        //window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                var str = window.location.hash;
                var res = str.replace("#bas", "");

                var div = document.getElementById(res);
                var rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();

                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: rect.top
                }, 500);
            }, 100)
        //})
    }

}
```

[image: Lister]

Detail :

[image: Detail]

Comment: Something here [Vue Scroll Behaviour](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) looks useful to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue Router supports [this behavior](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html).

**EDIT:**

All you need to do is add `scrollBehavior` to your `routerOptions`.

```
export default new Router({
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition;

    } else {
      return { x: 0, y: 0 };
    }
  },
  routes: []
});
```

Comment: How do i use this?

Comment: Ahh now i am getting a x and y. How do i pass this property to my products.vue ?

Comment: Just returning it should suffice.

Comment: What do i do in my products.vue to get the value?

Comment: Vue internally sets the scroll position automatically. You need not do anything.

Comment: Doesn't work, i have made a scroll function, but i need to push the savedPosition to my products.vue, how can i achieve that?

Comment: Can i view the app somewhere?